# How do I break up an extremely long string literal in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to embed a long command like this in a bash script:

```
mycommand \
    --server myserver \
    --filename extremely/long/file/name/that/i/would/like/to/be/able/to/break/up/if/possible \
    --otherflag \
    --anotherflag
```

with the long filename broken up.

I could do this:

```
# Insufficiently pretty
mycommand \
    --server myserver \
    --filename extremely/long/file/name/\
that/i/would/like/to/be/able/to/break/\
up/if/possible \
    --otherflag \
    --anotherflag \
```

but it breaks the flow. I would *like* to be able to write this:

```
# Doesn't work
mycommand \
    --server myserver \
    --filename extremely/long/file/name/\
         that/i/would/like/to/be/able/to/break/\
         up/if/possible \
    --otherflag \
    --anotherflag
```

but that doesn't work because it breaks up the string literal.

Is there a way to tell bash to break a string literal but ignore any leading spaces?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use a variable :

```
file=extremely/long/file/name
file+=/that/i/would/like/to/be/able/to/break
file+=/up/if/possible

mycommand\
    --server myserver\
    --filename $file\
    --flag flag
```

Comment: Good idea. You can make it cleaner though, by using the `+=` operator instead of `file=${file}/...`

Comment: +1: This is the least-obfuscated approach in my opinion. The intent is clear.

Comment: @Chriszuma Yes I forgot that bash allowed the `+=` operator. I edited my answer.

Comment: Search for some time for the solution, but all have tiny issues, like adding extra space between.  Thanks

Answer (score 86):

It's a <strike>bit of a</strike> hack, but this works:

```
mycommand \
    --server myserver \
    --filename "extremely/long/file/name/"`
               `"that/i/would/like/to/be/able/to/break/"`
               `"up/if/possible" \
    --otherflag \
    --anotherflag
```

Bash concatenates string literals that are adjacent, so we take advantage of that. For example, `echo "hi" "there"` prints `hi there` whereas `echo "hi""there"` prints `hithere`.

It also takes advantage of the backtick operator, and the fact that a bunch of spaces evaluates to nothing.

Comment: You can put the opening `\`` at the end of the preceding line, instead of the `​\​` line continustion... it keeps the left edge clean

Comment: @Peter.O I don't get what you're talking about. Please clarify.

Comment: a dirty hack to clean your code

Comment: I don't even think you need to close and reopen the double quotes. This works for me: `"one\` [line break] [whitespace] \`two"` -> `"onetwo"`

Answer (score 6):

Another way of writing a long string to a variable while keeping the maximum line length at bay:

```bash
printf -v fname '%s' \
    'extremely/long/file/name/that/i/' \
    'would/like/to/be/able/to/break/up/' \
    'if/possible'
```

Because there are more arguments than formatting directives, `%s` is just repeated and we get

```
$ declare -p fname
declare -- fname="extremely/long/file/name/that/i/would/like/to/be/able/to/break/up/if/possible"
```

which can be used like

```bash
mycommand \
    --server myserver \
    --filename "$fname" \
    --otherflag \
    --anotherflag
```

This is extra handy when setting long variables with inherently separated contents such as `CDPATH` (or `PATH`, of course):

```bash
printf -v CDPATH '%s' \
    ':/Users/benjamin/here/is/a/long/path' \
    ':/Users/benjamin/and/here/is/another/one' \
    ':/Users/benjamin/and/a/third/line'
export CDPATH
```

as opposed to

```bash
export CDPATH=':/Users/benjamin/here/is/a/long/path:/Users/benjamin/and/here/is/another/one:/Users/benjamin/and/a/third/line'
```

or the clunky

```bash
export CDPATH=':/Users/benjamin/here/is/a/long/path'
CDPATH+=':/Users/benjamin/and/here/is/another/one'
CDPATH+=':/Users/benjamin/and/a/third/line'
```

Answer (score 3):

One can also use an array variable

```
file=(extremely/long/file/name
    /that/i/would/like/to/be/able/to/break
    /up/if/possible)
IFS=''

echo mycommand\
    --server myserver\
    --filename "${file[*]}"\
    --flag flag
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there is nothing built into bash to do this.
A wrapper is typically more trouble than it's worth, but that said, you could try an alias or a funciton, eg. `j`

```
j(){sed -e ':a;$!N;s/ *\n *//g;ta' <<<"$1"}

echo "$(j "3   spaces  
           /hello
           /world
           /this
           /is
           /a
           /long
           /path
          ")"

# 3   spaces/hello/world/this/is/a/long/path
```

Answer (score 2):

I define a short strcat function at the top of my bash script and use an inline invocation to split things up. I sometimes prefer it to using a separate variable because I can define the long literal in-line with the command invocation.

```
function strcat() {
  local IFS=""
  echo -n "$*"
}

mycommand \
  --server myserver \
  --filename "$(strcat \
      extremely/long/file/name/ \
      that/i/would/like/to/be/able/to/break/ \
      up/if/possible)" \
  --otherflag \
  --anotherflag \
```

I also like this approach for when I have to enter a long CSV of values as a flag parameter because I can use it to avoid typing the comma between values:

```
function strjoin() {
  local IFS="$1"
  shift
  echo -n "$*"
}

csv_args=(
  foo=hello
  bar=world
  "this=arg  has  spaces  in  it"
)
mycommand \
  --server myserver \
  --csv_args "$(strjoin , "${csv_args[@]}")" \
  --otherflag \
  --anotherflag \
```

Which is equivalent to

```
mycommand \
  --server myserver \
  --csv_args "foo=hello,bar=world,this=arg  has  spaces  in  it" \
  --otherflag \
  --anotherflag \
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, one could use a `heredoc`:

```
command=$(cat << EOF
This
    is
    "a command"
    "that spans"
        multiple
        lines
EOF
)
command=$(echo $command)
echo $command
```

which results in

```
This is "a command" "that spans" multiple lines
```