# Escaping a space in bash

Tags: linux, bash, escaping, cmake

It's not a trivial questions, apparently, since I haven't found a solution so far by googling or searching in SO.  Anyway, if this is a duplicate, I'm sorry for posting it.

I'm writing a bash function for configuring a cmake build.  I save my cmake arguments in a variable like this:

```
CMAKEARGS=".. "`
         `"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${build_type} "`
         `"-DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=${boost_dir} "`
         `"-DGCL=ON "`
         `"-DENABLE_PERFORMANCE_METERS=OFF "`
         `"-DENABLE_CACHING=ON "`
         `"-DENABLE_CUDA_STREAMS=ON "`
         `"-DENABLE_LOGGING=OFF "
```

At some point, I have to add the following argument: `-DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-I${mpi_path}/include -ccbin=$(which g++)"`

If As you see, there are quotes `"` that I obviously have to escape (and this is not a problem), and a space between two "sub-arguments" that is causing a lot of trouble.  I tried the following:

```
CMAKEARGS+="'-DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS=\"-I${mpi_path}/include -ccbin=$(which g++)\"' "
```

At the end, the content of CMAKEARGS is: `... -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-I/opt/cray/mpt/6.2.1/gni/mpich2-cray/81/include -ccbin=/opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/g++" ...`, which looks really ok.  If I copy-paste this into my shell, it works just fine.  But if I use

```
cmake $CMAKEARGS
```

from within my functions, it thinks -ccbin=/opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/g++" (not there is just one quote `"`) is the source directory and fails.  How can I escape this space?  I tried putting a `\` in front of it, surround the whole argument with single quotes, double quotes,...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those really backticks around all your option strings? That's not going to go over very well...

Comment: Why? I followed the second answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729023/how-do-i-break-up-an-extremely-long-string-literal-in-bash, which works just fine. I use this to keep the left side indented.  I used to put backslashes at the end of the line, but this prevented me from indenting the next one.

Comment: Because backticks interpret the text inside them, attempt to execute it as a command, capture the output of that command, and replace the whole backtick-enclosed sequence with that output. Last I knew, `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${build_type}` was not an executable command, so it will fail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot safely embed spaces in a string like this; there is no way, after expanding `CMAKEARGS`, to know which spaces are data and which simply separate words (or rather, `bash` assumes all spaces are word splitters; embedded quotation marks are treated literally, not as quoting operators). This is why shell arrays were invented.

```
declare -a CMAKEARGS   # optional, the assignment that follows is sufficient
CMAKEARGS=(..
           "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${build_type}"
           "-DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=${boost_dir}"
           "-DGCL=ON"
           "-DENABLE_PERFORMANCE_METERS=OFF"
           "-DENABLE_CACHING=ON"
           "-DENABLE_CUDA_STREAMS=ON"
           "-DENABLE_LOGGING=OFF"
)
```

To use it:

```
cmake "${CMAKEARGS[@]}" ...
```

The array will expand into a sequence of quoted words, one per element. This way, any whitespace in an array element is preserved, and not used literally. It's equivalent to

```
cmake "${CMAKEARGS[0]}" "${CMAKEARGS[1]}" ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I was looking for.  To complete the answer, adding new arguments to the list can be done with `CMAKEARGS+=("mynewargument", "my second new argument")`.

Comment: @Spiros Almost; the comma would be taken as part of the first element, not as a separator. :) `CMAKEARGS+=("mynewargument" "my second new argument")`